# Drupal 7 how many blocks in region?

Tags: 7, theming

I need to know how many blocks in the region! is there any short way to do that ?
if more than one block in the region than I want to add custom class to region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use `hook_preprocess_region()` in a module or theme:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  // Make sure it's the right region
  if ($vars['region'] == 'sidebar_first') {
    // Get the count of blocks
    $count = count(element_children($vars['elements']));

    // Add the class if necessary
    if ($count > 1) {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'some-class';
    }
  }
}
```